# getting error in linking foreign key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, web-development-server

I'm getting error while linking foreign key. It should show 1,2,3,5 instead it's showing some negative numbers. You may open the image to understand it properly.

[image]

Comment: SO is for programming questions, this question is for phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your image its not negative values. Phpmyadmin shows foreign key in prepend and append both. Foreign key has been set successfully in your case.